# PHP can not handle inserting content for TEXTAREA if value contains HTML tags or special characters

Tags: php, html, textarea, special-characters, return-value

I have a table with some fields. I want to put their contents into HTML inputs.
Everything is ok, but I have just one problem on Textarea.
I want to fill textarea with stored contents. If it has no HTML tags or special characters, the code I have used works fine, otherwise I can not see anything for textarea.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT description FROM tblTest");
$returned_content = mysql_result($query,0);
?>
<textarea name="description"><?php echo $returned_content; ?></textarea>
```

For example if the field contains `123` , I can see this value for textarea. But if it be `123<br />321` I can not see anything.

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you try `<textarea name="description"><?php echo stripslashes(trim($returned_content)); ?></textarea>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it did not work too. Maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Is it just for line breaks? If so, look into [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the html metacharacters:

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($returned_content) ?></textarea>
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<textarea name="description"><?php echo html_entity_decode($returned_content); ?></textarea>
```

Add this between head tags

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Try this also

```
<textarea name="description"><?php echo htmlentities($returned_content); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you also using `<meta charset="utf-8">` ? @MohammadBagherSaberi and make sure to have `utf-8` database and not the default latin1.

Comment: try this <?php echo htmlentities($returned_content); ?>